# PING: command not found

Tags: unix, ping

Given the following code

```
pingval=$(ping6 -c 1 "$url")
time=$($pingval| tail -1| awk '{print $4}'|cut -d '/' -f 2)
```

Could anyone tell me why I'm receiving a PING: command not found error?

Comment: Try `time=$(ping6 -c 1 "$url" | tail -1| awk '{print $4}'|cut -d '/' -f 2)`. In your example, you are executing `$pingval` and that's the error I think. You can try adding `set -x` to your script and see what's happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution to this was to simply use

```
time=$(echo pingval|......)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm presuming you're wrapping this in a shell script? Is the ping6 command in the search path for the shell you're using to execute that script?

Also, stating the obvious: ping6 is also in your path?

```
which ping6
```

Comment: which ping6 returns /bin/ping6. 

The shell I'm using to execute my script?...
#!/bin/bash